# I'd like to make my font smoother than they are

Tags: css, sass, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I would like to make my fonts looks smoother than they are.

I have tried this code:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

But this doesnt seem to work aswell on the font I'm using.

Google Fonts are pretty smooth, but the ones I've imported doesnt seem to adhere to the line of code.

**nb: I'm using WOFF & WOFF2 files of Geomanist.**

I have seen many websites with clearly smooth fonts, as they were a little blurred.

How can I achieve this effect on my text?

I was also wondering if there wasn't a potential script to do this, but maybe my question sounds stupid too, excuse me just in case.

I can provide examples if asked.

[image: see? doesnt look smooth as much]

Answer (score 0):

There aren't many ways to finely tune the rendering of text in CSS, aside from prefixed, non-standard properties like `-webkit-font-smoothing` and `-moz-osx-font-smoothing`, both of which have [zero effect outside of macOS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth).

There are primarily two things that affect how a font will render at small sizes: hinting, and the rendering engine. Hinting is saved on the font file itself, and is either manually designed by the person making the font, or more commonly these days, automatic hinting is applied. Rendering engines are typically different on a per-operating system basis, but some applications have their own rendering engines, like Adobe's design apps.

So, given those difficulties, your best option might be to choose another font that renders better, unless you're interested in learning how to design fonts, which is a very long road to take (I am a font designer). Be sure to test your fonts to make sure they render well on a variety of OS/browser combinations.